# python list parsing example

Tags: python, list, split, string-parsing

I'd like to know how to parse (or split) and element of a list?

I have a list of lists (of string) such as:

```
resultList =  [['TWP-883 PASS'], ['TWP-1080 PASS'], ['TWP-1081 PASS']]
```

where:

```
resultList[0] = ['TWP-883 PASS']
resultList[1] = ['TWP-1080 PASS']
```

essentially, I need a variable for the two entries in each element of the list. For example:

```
issueId = 'TWP-883'
status = 'PASS'
```

What would allow for iterating through this list and parsing such as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I changed this answer to reflect an edit of the question. Specifically, I added a `split()` to separate the strings in the nested lists into two strings (`issueId` and `status`).

---

I would use list and dictionary comprehensions to turn your list of lists into a list of dictionaries with the keys `issueId` and `status`:

```
resultList =  [['TWP-883 PASS'], ['TWP-1080 PASS'], ['TWP-1081 PASS']]

result_dicts = [{("issueId","status")[x[0]]:x[1] for x in enumerate(lst[0].split())} for lst in resultList]
```

Lookups can now be done in this way:

```
>>> result_dicts[0]["status"]
'PASS'
>>> result_dicts[0]["issueId"]
'TWP-883'
>>> result_dicts[1]
{'status': 'PASS', 'issueId': 'TWP-1080'}
>>>
```

To declare variables for each value in each dictionary in the list and print them, use the code below:

```
for entry in result_dicts:
    issueId = entry["issueId"]
    status = entry["status"]
    print("The status of {0: <10} is {1}".format(issueId, status))
```

Output:

```
The status of TWP-883    is PASS
The status of TWP-1080   is PASS
The status of TWP-1081   is PASS
```

Comment: how would you unpack each item?

Comment: I've updated the question. Your assumptions in 'UPDATE' are correct. Thanks, I appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 5):

Well that's as simple as:

```
# You can also assign as you iterate as suggested in the comments.
for issue, status in resultList:
    print issue, status
```

This outputs

```
TWP-883 PASS
TWP-1080  PASS
TWP-1081  PASS
TWP-1082  PASS
TWP-884  FAIL
TWP-885  PASS
```

Here's another example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2] # or (1, 2), or '12' works with collections
>>> y, z = x
>>> y
1
>>> z
2
>>>
```

Incidentally, in Python 3.x, you can also do:

```
In [1]: x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [2]: y, z, *rest = x
In [3]: y
Out[3]: 1
In [4]: z
Out[4]: 2
In [5]: rest
Out[5]: [3, 4]
```

Comment: or just `for issueId,status in resultList` (+1 all the same)

Comment: thanks! This works great to iterate through the list with variable assignments

Comment: @webcrew, no worries, please accept the answer if it answers your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple `for` loop that exploits Python's tuple unpacking machinery.

```
for issueId, status in resultList:
    # Do stuff with issueId and status
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do more transformations later, use a genexp,

```
g = (func(issueid, status) for issueid, status in resultList) # func returns non-None objects
```

If you just want to consume the iterable,

```
for issueid, status in resultList:
    # print(issueid, status)
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of the strings by

```
issueId = [y for x in resultList for (i,y) in enumerate(x.split()) if(i%2==0)]
status = [y for x in resultList for (i,y) in enumerate(x.split()) if(i%2==1)]
```

to go through every issueID and corrosponding status you can use

```
for id,st in zip(issueId,status):
    print(id, " : ", st)
```